# Does TFS log undo checkouts?

Tags: version-control, tfs

Let's say someone checkedout some files and then he/she undo the checkout. Can I find those undo checkout tracks in TFS history? Where?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Current checkouts are tracked (obviously), but there is no history of changes to this list (it is just the current checkout/lock list).

History only includes checkins and the changes made in them.

---

Why do you want this information? There maybe a better approach to solving your underlying problem.

Answer (score 1):

No. As the un-done changes are never checked in they are not registered as a changeset in TFS and therefore not shown in the TFS history for a file or folder.

If you wanted to explain why you need to know when someone has performed an undo it might help in suggesting another way to accomplish what you want.