# How can I query TFS for a historical list of check OUT's?

Tags: version-control, vcs-checkout

I've got a client with recurring complaints about check-ins that fail to include some changes he makes, and he "loses" the changes.
The only common thread I could find to his complaints are that his developers use the Source Control Explorer to manually check out files.

I suspect human error. I suspect that they aren't checking out the files that later go missing.

Problem is that his people are adamant that they are doing everything right, and TFS (2010) is now suspect of being dangerously sub-standard.

I understand that in 2008, there was a TfsActivityLogging database that could show me a check-out history. In 2010, since they added collections, the structure changed, and I can't find a way to do that.

Does anybody know how I can find a **checkout** history for a certain file?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1327593/does-tfs-log-undo-checkouts Does that question somewhat cover what you are asking?

Comment: Unfortunately no, it doesn't. The post you suggested is about 2008, not 2010 (there are changes), and they refer to something else altogether.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

User activity, e.g. commmands issued to TFS, are logged in tbl_Command.  When I checkout I get a number of entries in this table, the most likely one being Command='PendChanges'.  I've used this query:

```
SELECT TOP 100
    *
FROM    
    [Tfs_DefaultCollection].[dbo].[tbl_Command] 
WHERE   
    Application = 'Version Control'
    AND IdentityName = '<domain>\<user>'
ORDER BY 
    commandid DESC
```

Comment: Hi, this gives me a list of the checkout (PendChanges) commands I initiated, but it doesn't tell me _which_ files I checked out. Is there another table I can join to, that might give me the answer?

Comment: I guess this is the closest I can get... :(